# Django delete models based on form input

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms

I have a form and a model, in my views I take the data from form and use it to delete the object from my model, but it does not delete the object at all, even though if I use the shell and create the same query set with the same syntax it works. What am I missing here?? Thx

Code from views:

```
form = SecondForm()

query_list = DictWord.objects.all()
dict_DictWord = {'words': query_list,"form":form}
if request.method == "POST":
    form = SecondForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        ##Does not delete the object from models
        data = form.cleaned_data['name']
        DictWord.objects.filter(name=data).delete()
        return render(request, 'appone/index.html', context = dict_DictWord)
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Error")

return render(request,'appone/index.html',context=dict_DictWord)
```

But if I use manage.py shell, I import my model and this syntax works, and it returns the dict with the deleted object:

```
from app.models import DictWord
DictWord.objects.filter(name="SomeName").delete()
```

Comment: You should add some logging statements. I suspect that `data` is not what you expect here. If the DictWord queryset is empty, `delete()` will return `0`, otherwise it will return the number of rows deleted.

Comment: You can also add a success message to display to the user. `messages.success(request, f'{deleted} records with name "{data}" deleted')`

Comment: Yes you are right, but the strange thing is that if the data matches with one of the name  attribute in the models, somehow it is empty (it is not printed) else if it is any other thing that is not in my models it is ok , it gets printed:                                                                                     
       `data = form.cleaned_data['name'] ` or I even tried                                           
       `data = request.POST.get('name')  print(data)`

Comment: Not printed? Where do you try printing?

Comment: `data = str(form.cleaned_data['name'])
    #data = request.POST.get('name')
            print(data)
            try:
                #DictWord.objects.filter(name=data).delete()
               model_instance = DictWord.objects.get(name=data)
               model_instance.delete()
            except:
                print("NOK")` In the first print I try to print the data taken from form, but the issue is that if the data (which is a string that corresponds to name attribute of the object) exist in my db , it will  not print it, else if is another string it will print it.

Comment: Are you sure `form.is_valid()` doesn't return`False`? Do you actually display the errors when the form is invalid? You should pass the form that you called `is_valid()` in the context. `is_valid` will modify the form object and add error messages that will be rendered in the template. Move the line `dict_DictWord = {'words': query_list,"form":form}` to just before the final `return render` line. Then the invalid `form` will be included in the context if validation failed.

Comment: Yes you are right, so I used on else branch of if form.is_valid() , `print(form.errors)` and it appears that actually the POST method want to add to models `<ul class="errorlist"><li>name<ul class="errorlist"><li>Dict word with this Name already exists.</li></ul></li></ul>`, but I don't understand why ?

Comment: Is SecondForm a ModelForm? That would explain it. This is not the intended usage of ModelForm.

Comment: Yes, is a ModelForm, basically I wanted to take the user input and then delete the object from models. Could you please point me to a resource that explains what is the best practice concerning this subject?  Thank you for your help, you are awesome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166919/discussion-between-distrobyte-and-haken-lid).

Answer (score 0):

```
#try this     
record=DictWord.objects.get(name=data)
record.delete()

        return render(request, 'appone/index.html', context = dict_DictWord)
```

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Model.objects.filter(name=data).delete() this results in deletion of bulk data,but as you want to delete a single record it is better to use Model.objects.get(name=data).delete()